# $fail() doesn't work on the closure of form request - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I notice that the $fail doesn't work on this following FormRequest.

it's "skipped" to the code on the controller directly

the expected result is it runs the code inside the `failedValidation()` , pretty much like `if ($validator->fails())` if we code the validation on the controller directly

```php
class MyFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    use ApiResponse;

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
             'file' => [
                'required',
                'file',
                'mimetypes:application/json,text/plain',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    $content = file_get_contents($value);
                    $json = json_decode($content, true);

                    if (!isset($json['fileName'])) {
                        $fail('Something error');
                    }
                }
            ]
        ];
    }

    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        return $this->errorResponse($validator->errors()->first());
    }
}

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function myIndex(MyFormRequest $request)
    {
        return 'something';
    }

}
```

what went wrong on this code?

Comment: `$fail` that's a variable? Not sure what are you trying to achieve really

Comment: it's a callback. reference: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#using-closures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself.

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException($this->errorResponse($validator->errors()->first()));
    }
```